# How to configure using Styleguidist with Apollo/GraphQL

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, react-styleguidist

I'm trying to use GraphQL to populate fake data for Styleguidist. I'm using Express to make my GraphQL server but **I'm unsure how to connect Apollo into Styleguidist**? The examples use the index.js file and wrap the root component in an tag for Apollo.

I am unsure how Styleguidist works, I don't know where the index.js file is.

There are ways to configure Styleguidist through webpack, but I don't know how to use webpack to use Apollo.

Comment: What examples are you referring to?

Comment: I am watching a class on Udemy, but also at https://blog.graph.cool/how-to-use-create-react-app-with-graphql-apollo-62e574617cff, if you scroll down to "Now we’re importing the needed packages in src/index.js". It is letting you know some configurations, but also recommending that the React.dom method look like:  ReactDOM.render((
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Route path='/' component={ListPage} />
      <Route path='/create' component={CreatePage} />
    </Router>
  </ApolloProvider>
  ),
  document.getElementById('root')
)

Comment: Is there a main index.js file for Styleguidist somewhere in the module?

Comment: I've tried wrapping the component, Button in the ApolloProvider tag, the error message that I get is: Invariant Violation: Could not find "client" in the context of "Apollo(Button)". Wrap the root component in an <ApolloProvider>

Comment: I'm trying to use Wrapper method as here: https://react-styleguidist.js.org/docs/cookbook.html#how-to-change-the-layout-of-a-style-guide But I don't think that's the ticket because it wraps all the individual components. It seems to me I need a way to wrap the root component, because that's what the examples do and that is the above error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each example in Styleguidist is rendered as an independent React tree, and the Wrapper component *is* the root component, so you need to override it as show in the Redux example like this:

```
// lib/styleguide/Wrapper.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ApolloClient, { createNetworkInterface } from 'apollo-client';
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo';
const client = new ApolloClient({ /* ... */ });
export default class Wrapper extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        {this.props.children}
      </ApolloProvider>
    );
  }
}


// styleguide.config.js
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  styleguideComponents: {
    Wrapper: path.join(__dirname, 'lib/styleguide/Wrapper')
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

So you can use Styleguidist in two ways, one by using Create React App then installing an NPM Styleguidist package. Then the other method that I found is starting from an example github registry and replacing the components as you go. I had done the first: where I used Create React App so Webpack was not installed in my main folder but was being used in the NPM module.

With that method I was getting the error:

"Module parse failed: Unexpected token (16:6)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type."

Which means that I needed to configure Webpack. I didn't solve this, but it may just need to have styleguide.config.js file configured to work with Babel. (just a guess)

So, could not (so far), successfully use the Wrapper that solves the problem. So instead I downloaded an example of Styleguidist at https://github.com/styleguidist/example and started fresh. I'm not sure what the difference is, but when I used a wrapper it worked well to add an ApolloProvider wrapper to every component on my page.

To get Apollo 2 to work though you also need to use HttpLink and InMemoryCache. The have a general setup about this at: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/basics/setup.html. Under creating a client.

I was using a different port for my GraphQL server because it was using a GraphQL/Express server at port 4000 and Styleguidist by default is at port 6060. So I did two things: passed a uri to the new HttpLink and added a line to the express server to allow cors.

The ref for cors in Express GraphQl and Apollo server:
https://blog.graph.cool/enabling-cors-for-express-graphql-apollo-server-1ef999bfb38d

So my wrapper file looks like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ApolloClient, { createNetworkInterface } from 'apollo-client';
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo';
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';

const link = new HttpLink({
  uri: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql'
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link,
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});

export default class Wrapper extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        {this.props.children}
      </ApolloProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

and my server file looks like:

```
const express = require('express');
const expressGraphQL = require('express-graphql');
const schema = require('./schema/schema');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use('/graphql', expressGraphQL({
  schema: schema
  , graphiql: true
}));

app.listen(4000, () => {
  console.log('..listening');
});
```